# Python multiprocessing on Amazon EC2 eventually resorts to single core

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-multiprocessing

I am running into a very weird problem on an Amazon instance running python and multiprocessing.

**The context**

I want to use `pool.map` or something similar (`imap_unordered` would do the trick too) to apply a CPU intensive task to an iterable. The iterable isn't that big (few hundred) but the task takes a long time.

I'm using the `multiprocessing` module of Python, in Python 2.7.11

The general structure is:

```
for longer_loop:
  for small loop:
    pool = Pool(processes=18)
    pool.map(f, iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**The problem**

I start the run. I go and look at "top" and see that Python is nicely using all them cores. I go and work on something else. I come back and see that all of a sudden Python is still in the longer loop but now uses only one core, and completely stopped taking advantage of the multiprocessing. To emphasize: It doesn't *hang*. Stuff is still happening. But it's happening one item at a time, instead of 18.

**Things I tried (that didn't help)**

First instinct: This is a load balancing issue, since the function takes a long yet slightly variable time, so some cores are just finishing earlier. Set chunksize to 1 since the bottleneck is definitely the function being applied, not the creation of lots of chunks. That didn't help.

Second instinct: I vaguely remember that numpy and python multiprocessing did not gel very well. Set `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` in the environment variables. While that *seemed* to help at first (via making everything run faster), a run with longer execution time (more data than my "let's test this stuff on small things first") still got stuck at the "only one thread".

Note: I had the creation of the pool outside the small loop, but that didn't change anything. The actual execution of the map takes the most time, so closing and recreating Pool objects would be insignificant.

**More suspicions of what it could be**

Currently trying a run where I deal with that *core affinity* issue, but I feel like if that was the issue then I should see it from the start, not at some undetermined later time.

Is there something weird about the Amazon EC2 instance that says "enough cores for you, fool!" after creating too many processes?

Could it have to do with using too much memory? But then I'd just expect to still see 18 hardworking (and 1 monitoring) python processes, just now they're all busy swapping stuff because they're out of memory. But I really just see a single working process (and the 1 monitoring process) toiling away at the loop, as if `map` or `imap_unordered`) decided that 1 was enough now. Which... just shouldn't happen.

Happy for any clues and pointers, and happy to provide more information if required.

Comment: [Add some logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#logging) inside the `f` function so you can get a "play-by-play" of when each process is working on which item from `iterable`. Log the value of the argument `f` is being applied to so you can see if `f` (perhaps) is hanging when passed a particular argument.

Comment: Thanks. But the program doesn't *hang*, it just stops using multiple cores. It still grinds along, just painfully slowly so.

Comment: Yet another case of real life https://xkcd.com/979/ . Anyone?

Comment: Hah, I don't even remember if I eventually figured out the solution or not... Python multiprocessing is surely a tricky beast.